# Twitter stream APIs, allotted requests for search stream APIs v2

Tags: twitter, bearer-token, twitter-streaming-api

I'm new to Twitter APIs (this is my first experience), and I'm playing with them to monitor an account for new tweets, opening a web page when it happens, but I'm having some doubt on understanding how the allotting works.

Not knowing much, the [twitter stream v2 APIs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/integrate/consuming-streaming-data) seem the ones fitting my use case, and in the [Twitter-API-v2-sample-code git repository](https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code) there is also a very clear [filtered stream nodejs example](https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/master/Filtered-Stream/filtered_stream.js). In fairness, I had little hassle to implement everything, and my code is not much different from [filtered_stream.js source code](https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/master/Filtered-Stream/filtered_stream.js). Given the provided example, implementation is straightforward: I use `https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream/rules` to setup my rules (an array like `[ { 'value': 'from:<myAccount>' } ]` and then I start to listen at `https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream`, easy peasy.

What I don't understand is the allotting resources count, because [as per Twitter documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/api-reference/get-tweets-search-stream) I should be able to make 50 requests every 15 minutes, but I can barely make a couple, thus every time I'm testing my script I have to wait a couple of minutes before restarting.

These are the relevant headers I received after restarting a script running since one hour (the status code at restart was 429):

- x-rate-limit-limit: 50
- x-rate-limit-remaining: 49
- Reset time: *+15 minutes from current time*

I usually don't have to wait 15 minutes, just a couple usually is fine... And my other note is that i managed to arrive down to 45 x-rate-limit-remaining once or twice, but never lower than that (usually I'm locked out at 47 / 48).

What I don't understand is: I opened one stream, I closed that one stream, and now I'm locked out for a couple of minutes. Allegedly, shouldn't I be able to open up to 50 connection in 15 minutes? (which is actually plenty if I'm just debugging a portion of code). Even the headers says that I have 49 attempts remaining out of 50, the status code 429 seems in pure contradiction with the x-rate-limits ... Sometimes, I cannot even reset the rules and start the stream in the same run, because the stream will return a backoff (status 429) when the rules resetting finishes (get -> set -> delete)...

I could add my code, but it's literally the [NodeJS example](https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/master/Filtered-Stream/filtered_stream.js) I cited above, and my problem is not about querying the APIs, but rather not being able to connect for no apparent reason (at least to me). The only thing I could think of is the fact that I use the same Bearer for all requests (as per their example), but I don't see written anywhere it is a problem (I generated it in the developer dashboard, I'm not sure there is an API for that as well).

**Edit - adding details**

Just to describe my issue, this is the output I get when I start the script the first time:

```
Headers for stream received (status 200): 
 - [x-rate-limit-limit]: 50
 - [x-rate-limit-remaining]: 49
 - [x-rate-limit-reset]: 20/03/2021, 11:05:35
```

Which make sense, I made one request, remaining count went down by one.

Now, I stopped it, and ran it immediately after (Ctrl + C, run again, let's say two seconds delay), and this is the new output:

```
Headers for stream received (status 429): 
 - [x-rate-limit-limit]: 50
 - [x-rate-limit-remaining]: 48
 - [x-rate-limit-reset]: 20/03/2021, 11:05:35
```

With the following exception being returned in the body:

```json
{
  title: 'ConnectionException',
  detail: 'This stream is currently at the maximum allowed connection limit.',
  connection_issue: 'TooManyConnections',
  type: 'https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/streaming-connection'
}
```

I understand the server takes a bit to realise I disconnected, but don't I have 50 connections available in a 15 minutes timeframe? I only opened one connection.

Actually, After the time it took to write all of the above (let's say ten minutes), I was able to connect again, receveing with this output:

```
Headers for stream received (status 200): 
 - [x-rate-limit-limit]: 50
 - [x-rate-limit-remaining]: 47
 - [x-rate-limit-reset]: 20/03/2021, 11:05:35
```

Maybe I'm realising only now and I wrote a useless question, but can I only have **one** active connection, being able to close it and open it again 50 times in 15 minutes? I understood I could have 50 active connections, but maybe at this point I'm wrong (and the Twitter server indeed takes a few minutes to realise I disconnected).

Comment: Same issue here 3 months later, must be an error on Twitters side. There is a discussion about this here: https://twittercommunity.com/t/rate-limit-on-tweets-stream-api/144389

Comment: I realised, I though I was going out crazy (I trusted their documentation, and I have no experience with it). I ended up switched to the v1 of the APIs, since it's also faster in retrieving notifications (~6-10 seconds faster).